# Does not add data to json file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have red a lot of posts about how to add data to json file and I tried to put it all together and use for my situation, but it's not working. Basically what I do is get data from html file with javascript, then use XMLHttp request to send that data to php file and from php file I am trying to add the data to .json file. Anywho, it is not adding it and I don't know why and where is the problem.
My question is about the XMLHttp request. Is it correct? Why not? 
And about php file. If the problem is in XMLHttp request, would the php file add the data to .json file? I am just trying to get anything in the json file, so i could start thinking about algorithms for making it viable. XMLHttp request is pretty new thing for me. For understanding, here is my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/style_mob.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="script/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="script/sendData.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top">
            <h1>Click only in case of an emergency!</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="divButtons">
            <button class="button" id="polizei">Polizei</button>
            <button class="button" id="feuerwehr">Feuerwehr</button>
            <button class="button" id="krankenwagen">Krankenwagen</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

sendData.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var type;
    var latitude;
    var longitude;
    var currentdate = new Date();
    $(".button").click(function(){
        type = $(this).attr("id");        

        var dateTime = "Date: " + currentdate.getDay() + "/"+(currentdate.getMonth()+1) 
            + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear() + " time - " 
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getMinutes();

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendData);
        } else {
           alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
        function sendData(position) {
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;          
        }
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("POST", "emergencyData.php", true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        alert("about to send data to php file");
        hr.send("type="+type+"&latitude="+latitude+"&longitude="+longitude+"$dateTime="+currentdate+"");
    });


});
```

emergencyData.php:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $latit = $_POST["latitude"];
    $longit = $_POST["longitude"];
    $dateTime = $_POST["dateTime"];
    echo $type;
    // Loading existing data:
    $json = file_get_contents("emergencyData.json");
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    // Adding new data:
    $data[0] = array('type' => $type, 'latitude' => $latit, 'longitude' => $longit, 'date' => $dateTime);

    // Writing modified data:
    file_put_contents('emergencyData.json', json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
?>
```

Comment: You can start debugging this by using the network tab in Chrome's dev tools. See if the proper request is going to the server, and see if the proper thing is being sent back in response. Once you've ensured the AJAX request (xmlhttp...) works properly, you can start debugging the php logic. Currently, it looks like you're not appending the new data, rather you're always setting the data to the 0th index, replacing whatever was there before. So look into how to append data to an array in php. Also: as long as you're using jQuery, you should use $.AJAX instead of XMLHttpRequest. It's simpler.

Comment: just to be sure, do you have a webserver set up or are you trying to do this locally?

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention. I am trying this at free online webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in javascript.

```
hr.send("type="+type+"&latitude="+latitude+"&longitude="+longitude+"$dateTime="+currentdate+"");
```

You have a `$` at `dateTime` which should be `&`

Also I think you wanted `&dateTime="+currentdate+""` to be `&dateTime="+dateTime`. Extra `+""` is unnecessary.

And last thing, if you want to keep adding new data instead of overwriting old data, in PHP script use:

```
$data[] = array('type' => $type, 'latitude' => $latit, 'longitude' => $longit, 'date' => $dateTime);
```

Otherwise everytime the old JSON data will get replaced by new one.

Comment: I changed everything you suggested. This is what im getting in console in Firefox: 1. `POST 
XHR 
http://projectforuni.byethost32.com/emergencyData.php`

2. `GET 
XHR 
http://parked-domain.org/`

3. `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://parked-domain.org/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

Comment: Well the `http://projectforuni.byethost32.com/emergencyData.php` is being redirected to `http://parked-domain.org/` which is why you're getting that error. Why is it being redirected? You'll have to ask your host for that.

Comment: Thank you, I set up my own wamp server so there would be no misunderstandings and it works! Thank you.